# Typescript - Add types for 'promisifed' methods

Tags: node.js, typescript

I have a very simple module that wraps the "fs" module.
This module simply "promisifies" all of "fs" methods and exports the new object:

*fsWrapper.ts*

```
import Promise from "bluebird";
import * as fs from "fs";

const fsWrapper = Promise.promisifyAll(fs);

export = fsWrapper;
```

Now I can use this wrapper instead of "promisifiying" the "fs" module inside every caller module, like so:

*main.ts*

```
import fsWrapper from "./fsWrapper";

function test(): void {
    fsWrapper.readFileAsync("tst.txt", "utf8")
    .then((data: Buffer) => {
        console.log("data:", data.toString());
})
```

}

This of course doesn't work with typescript since "fs" doesn't hold the `readFileAsync` method and I receive a compiler error.

While searching of ways of properly typings this wrapper, I found the [following typescript issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8685).

Using its approach, I can create my own `fsWrapper.d.ts`, in which I need to manually add the *Async methods, similar to the following:

*fsWrapper.d.ts*

```
import Promise from "bluebird";

declare module "fs" {
    export function readFileAsync(path: string, options: { encoding?: string | null; flag?: string; } | string | undefined | null) : Promise<Buffer>;
    ...
}
```

The problem here is:

1. Manually adding all the needed methods is tedious and error prone.
2. If these methods will change in future versions, I will have no idea as my code will keep compiling and I will suffer runtime exceptions.

I know that `util.promisify` is properly typed, and therefore thought of somehow extending "fs" with these new methods, similar to the following:

*fsWrapperTest.ts*

```
import * as fs from "fs";
import { promisify } from "util";

let fsWrapper = fs;
fsWrapper.readFileAsync = promisify(fs.readFile);

export = fsWrapper;
```

But this outputs an error that indicates that I can't extend existing modules: 
`error TS2551: Property 'readFileAsync' does not exist on type 'typeof "fs"'. Did you mean 'readFileSync'?`

Is there any way for me to properly type this wrapper while keeping "up-to-date" typings and working with Intellisense?

**Edit:**
Just to clarify, I understand how to create an object that will have all "fs" methods promisified (that was the case with the original `fsWrapper.ts` above).

What i'm struggling is typing it properly for Intellisense usage.
For example, running the following:

```
import * as fs from "fs";
import { promisify } from "util";

let fsWrapper = Object.keys(fs).reduce((p: typeof fs, v: string) => { p[v] = promisify(fs[v]); return p }, {})
```

Will give me a `fsWrapper: {}` typing for the object.

I would like to have all of "fs" methods + the new 'promisifed' methods as its type.

**EDIT - selected solution**

I ended up using the `declare module 'fs'` approach by extending the 'fs' module with all the *Async methods that I was using in my code.
Not ideal but it seems that there is no better alternative..

Comment: There's already a built-in module for Nodejs, [`util`, that includes a `promisify` method](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v8.x/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original)...

Comment: As I mentioned in my question, I tried using this module to extend 'fs' (see the `fsWrapperTest.ts` section), but that didn't work.
Could you please explain how I can use it in order to type my wrapper module?

Comment: `let wrap = Object.keys(fs).reduce((p, v) => { p[v] = util.promisify(fs[v]); return p }, {})`

Comment: @unional please see my edit.

Comment: I see, there is no way to construct a different name from the original type.

Answer (score 7):

If you are using TypeScript 3.0 or newer, the improvements to mapped types and parameter tuples should make this possible.  For example:

```
type UnpackedPromise<T> = T extends Promise<infer U> ? U : T
type GenericFunction<TS extends any[], R> = (...args: TS) => R
type Promisify<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends GenericFunction<infer TS, infer R>
        ? (...args: TS) => Promise<UnpackedPromise<R>>
        : never
}
```

That creates a type for unwrapping a promise, a type for a generic function, and then an inferred mapped type for the promisified version that maps each key to a new value that is the promisified version of the previous function.  To use that type ([playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=type%20UnpackedPromise%3CT%3E%20%3D%20T%20extends%20Promise%3Cinfer%20U%3E%20%3F%20U%20%3A%20T%0D%0Atype%20GenericFunction%3CTS%20extends%20any%5B%5D%2C%20R%3E%20%3D%20(...args%3A%20TS)%20%3D%3E%20R%0D%0Atype%20Promisify%3CT%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5BK%20in%20keyof%20T%5D%3A%20T%5BK%5D%20extends%20GenericFunction%3Cinfer%20U%2C%20infer%20V%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3F%20(...args%3A%20U)%20%3D%3E%20Promise%3CUnpackedPromise%3CV%3E%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3A%20never%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20original%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20one%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%201%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20two%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%202%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20add%3A%20(a%3A%20number%2C%20b%3A%20number)%20%3D%3E%20a%20%2B%20b%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20promisified%20%3D%20original%20as%20unknown%20as%20Promisify%3Ctypeof%20original%3E%0D%0A%0D%0Apromisified.one()%0D%0Apromisified.add(1%2C%202)%0D%0A)):

```
const original = {
    one: () => 1,
    two: () => 2,
    add: (a: number, b: number) => a + b
}

const promisified = original as unknown as Promisify<typeof original>

promisified.one()
promisified.add(1, 2)
```

And for your example, here's how that would be used:

```
import * as fs from "fs";
import { promisify } from "util";

let fsWrapper = Object
    .keys(fs)
    .reduce((p: typeof fs, v: string) => { p[v] = promisify(fs[v]); return p }, {}) as unknown as Promisify<typeof fs>
```

Notice that you are casting to unknown and then to `Promisify<*>` - this is because by default it will consider the mapped type to be possibly a mistake.

Comment: I tried using your code but the Intellisense is still offering me the non-async method of readFile (for example) when I try to use fsWrapper.

Comment: This seems to work great unless the return type of a method is `this`. It resolves it to the "parent" type instead of keeping it. This makes it impossible to extend.

Comment: In TypeScript 4.5 one could use `Awaited` instead of `UnpackedPromise`: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-5.html#the-awaited-type-and-promise-improvements

Answer (score 3):

Node.js >= v10.x started to provide already promisified functions.

You can use them via `require("fs").promises` or `require("fs/promises")` (>= v14.x)

https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v10.x/api/fs.html#fs_fs_promises_api
https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v14.x/api/fs.html#fs_fs_promises_api

I use

```js
const fs = { ...require("fs"), ...require("fs/promises") };
```

Answer (score 2):

There is an existing thread on github exactly for this, see https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8685

So, you can do something like:

```
import { Promise } from 'bluebird';
import * as fs from "fs";

declare module "fs" {
    interface fs {
        [method: string]: any;
    }
}

const fsWrapper = Promise.promisifyAll(fs);
export = fsWrapper;
```

This is already very similar to what you were doing to get past the issue of calling the methods.

Please note that as far as I know the only way to allow full Intellisense is to do module augmentation as described in the typescript documentation https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html

But that implies you manually writing the interface for the new methods generated by the promisified inside that module structure above. i.e.

```
declare module "fs" {
    interface fs {
        readFileAsync(... ),
        writeFileAsyng(... ),
        etc ...
    }
}
```